# Galactic Core location

Tags: star-wars

In Star Wars then there is a pair of systems of coordinates, one for the more abstract grid units, and one for the more precise XYZ coordinates.

The systems both use Coruscant as their Origin (The 0,0,0, coordinate) rather than the most logical place to put it, the Galactic Core.

With that, where in the XYZ-coordinate system is the Galactic Center?

Comment: The actual Galactic Center is just a massively huge black hole, which is what makes the Deep Core difficult to navigate. I'm not sure it even HAS coordinates assigned to it, since that entire area would be a huge no-fly zone.

Comment: Well, assuming these coordinates are made using Euclidean geometry (the standard "XYZ" 3D space), there would *have to be* coordinates for the galactic core.  The three planes that compose the coordinate grid will go on to infinity in all axial directions, and the galactic core will be *somewhere* in that space.  You can move (0, 0, 0) off-center if you want (ie: put it on Coruscant) but there will still be a range of numbers "blocked out" by the core, and those ranges will describe a set of coordinates that it occupies.

Comment: You would need to convert the grid system to XYZ. According to the Star Wars reference site, Galactic core is located at K-11 in the Deep Core https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/d/d8/TheDeepCore-TEA.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20090904101129

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we take the [*Star Wars: The Essential Atlas*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Essential_Atlas) as a reasonable source for galactic coordinates, we can see that Coruscant is at 0, 0, 0 and that **the Galactic Core is at 0, -150, ?**

[image]

The book also uses an older alphanumerical system, placing the Galactic Center at **L-11.5 on a 2-D map of the galaxy.**

[image]